# How to enter data from pdf from into website

Tags: html, pdf, pdf-form

I would like to create a program/script that exports data from pdf form fields and input it in the website's corresponding textfields (I have to do it from the front-end).

The problem is that I don't know at all where to start.

Could you share your ideas and advise me where could I find some materials that would help me start?

I've been searching for it but I found information only about web scraping which is quite the opposite of what I want to achieve.

Moreover I don't know which languages would be suitable for such a solution.

Comment: Voted to close as "too broad"

Comment: Hi @blagae I see your comment, but I don't see your vote. Currently, there's only one close vote (mine). This question needs a lot of work before it's eligible for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie users with less than 3,000 reputation can only flag, not vote, to close. A flag to close will simply submit a question to the close vote queue, but not add one of the necessary close votes required to close it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iText` to extract the values from PDF form fields.
https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/form-examples/clone-get-information-form

If you use a framework like Spring, you can then easily inject those values into a form (e.g. displayed by ThymeLeaf).

Comment: Trawa wants to "do this on the front-end." That kind of limits Trawa's options. I agree with you that going with iText is an option, but not on the front-end. Trawa will have to make a design where the PDF is sent to a server and where the HTML is served by that server. Doing all of this on the client is only possible if Trawa wants to build a desktop application (but I don't have the impression this is the case).